# Anyone have experience getting openmaptiles planet autoupdate to work?

Tags: openmaptiles

I've been trying to get the provided autoupdate scripts to work.  While it does seem to be doing something, it isn't doing what I expect.  First, it isn't respecting the tmp folder provided.  Instead it is using the /tmp folder of the OS, which isn't large enough to handle the complete update or planet file backup.

Second, the logfile isn't being generated.  Maybe it would if the process completes?

Does anyone have experience with the autoupdate script that could help explain why its not working as expected?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, user error.  I am not great with Ubuntu so sought the help of a *nix guru friend.  I'd assumed that being in the directory with autoupdate it would use that file when I called "sudo autoupdate ...".  It did not.  Instead it was using /usr/bin/autoupdate which is completely different and didn't take the same parameters.  It's working now.